# How to refer to a method defined in a derived class only, using an upcast unique_ptr pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, unique-ptr, upcasting

Assume following classes

```
class Base
{
   void Doajob(a,b){...}
}

class Derived: public Base
{
   void Doanotherjob(a,b,c){...}
}
```

I have defined a pointer as follows:

```
 auto ptr= unique_ptr<Base>(new Derived(name));
```

Now I want to access Doanotherjob using the ptr pointer:

```
ptr->Doanotherjob(a,b,c); // ERROR
((unique_ptr<Base>) ptr)->Doanotherjob(a,b,c); // ERROR
((unique_ptr<Derived>) ptr)->Doanotherjob(a,b,c); // ERROR
```

Is that even a right thing to do? What is the syntax?

Comment: On a side note, downcasting to a derived class violates LSP and is *usually* indicative of a flaw in your design.

Comment: Even with a regular pointer you wouldn't able to make this call, unless via a downcast, since you don't access an overridden function

Comment: `Base` must have a virtual destructor, otherwise the `unique_ptr` will cause UB when it tries to `delete` the pointer

Comment: I guess you meant to derive `Derived` from `Base`, rather than from itself

Comment: Yes, I changed the word Derived to Base.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know for sure that the downcast is safe, you can use `static_cast`.

```
static_cast<derived*>(ptr.get())->DoAnotherJob(...);
```

However, if you made `DoAnotherJob()` virtual in `base`, then the downcast is unnecessary.  This is a much more traditional object-oriented approach.

As stated in the comments below, `dynamic_cast` let's you do this cast and verify the result:

```
if(auto d = dynamic_cast<derived*>(ptr.get())
   d->DoAnotherJob();
```

Comment: perhaps `dynamic_cast` as it allows you to test whether the result is ok?

Comment: I could not make 'code' DoAnotherjob() virtual in base as type of c is not defined in Base. I tried making a virtual DoAnotherjob(TypeofA a,TypeofB b, vector<Derived::TypeofCelement> c) but it did not work. So I tried to bypass the Base class criteria and send the arguments directly to the derived class. 

Also I have a container of pointers to Base class which may or may not be possible to be downcasted to derive class. I think I can use dynamic_cast o check as above mentioned. Am I right?

Comment: Yes `dynamic_cast` in the example above will return `nullptr` if the conversion fails so the body of the `if` statement will not be executed in that case.

Comment: The `dynamic_cast` version will only work if `Base` has a virtual function. However using the `unique_ptr` is UB anyway if `Base` did not have a virtual destructor.